# Passing derived class pointer to function expecting base pointer by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a key-value container class that holds pointers to heap-allocated objects of a base type. The insert method of the container instantiates one of 2 **derived** class objects (based on a runtime flag) and inserts it into itself.

I have a `Find` method with the following signature:

```
bool Find(int key, Base *&result);
```

The classes that use of this container know which derived class is *actually* being stored, because there is a one-to-one mapping between a user of the class and one of the derived types.

So when a user tries to call the Find method as follows:

```
DerivedA *a = nullptr;
bool found = container.Find(10, a);
```

I get a compiler error saying that there is no matching function.

So it seems that implicit conversion isn't happening between the base and derived classes. I suspect it has to do with the fact that I'm passing the pointer by reference, but I'm not sure.

What is the "correct" way to achieve what I'm after here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just return a pointer? `Base* Find(int key);`

Comment: @juanchopanza that's actually a great idea, but I would still love to know why the above doesn't work

Comment: what do you think the `*&` means?

Comment: @Fureeish `*&` means reference to pointer.

Comment: @AlexD I'm aware of what it is. I just don't think OP knows. In the code he is trying to pass a pointer, which is pointing to null. Reference of a null is not something that can be worked with

Comment: @Fureeish null-references are not allowed. References to pointers (including null-pointers) are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect it has to do with the fact that I'm passing the pointer by reference

Imagine that `Find` updates the passed pointer and now it points at a new instance of `Base`. But the caller still interprets it as a pointer to `DerivedA`.

Basically the issue is that you can assign

```
Base* basePtr = &derived;
```

but not the way around. So if the only guarantee of your `Find` method is that it finds an instance of `Base` type, we cannot just assign the pointer to it to `DerivedA`.

If you do know that your `Base` class pointer points at `DerivedA`, you could consider [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
Base* Find(int key);
....
DerivedA* a = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(Find(key));
```

(Returning the pointer might be better, as **@juanchopanza** comment suggests.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Add an overload of Find

```
Base *pi=result;
bool r=Find(key,pi);
result=dynamic_cast<DerivedA *>(pi);
return r;
```